# Django ModelForm; User, this field is required

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am having some issues with a (model)form consisting of just a single button. When I try to submit the form this message is displayed:

> user
>   This field is required.

The ModelForm looks like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import HulpOproep


class HulpOproepForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HulpOproep
        fields = ['user', ]
```

The Model looks like this:

```
class HulpOproep(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Tijd')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.username, str(self.time))

    def username(self):
        return self.user.username

    def first_name(self):
        return self.user.first_name

    def last_name(self):
        return self.user.last_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Hulp Oproep'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Hulp Oproepen'
```

The View looks like this:

```
def verzend_oproep(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HulpOproepForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            oproep = form.save(commit=False)
            oproep.user = request.user
            oproep.save()
            return redirect('portal/index/')
    else:
        form = HulpOproepForm()
    return render(request, 'portal/verzend_oproep.html', {'form': form})
```

The Template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
    <title>Zorggroep | Hulp Oproep</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body%}
    <h1>Verstuur Hulpoproep</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_P }}
        {{ form.errors }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Verstuur</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The 'user' in the HulpOproep model is a ForeignKey and should be the currently logged in user's User object. I tried to specify this using the line:

```
oproep.user = request.user
```

So what should happen is:
Get the current user's 'User' object and use it as the 'HulpOproepForm.user'. This way the 'HulpOproepForm.user' is the 'HulpOproep.user' and a Foreign Key.

I have followed multiple tutorials and have searched around, but I cannot find a solution. I'm sorry if the answer is logical, but I have been using Django for only 5 days and have 1.5 months of programming experience under my belt.

Thank you!

Comment: As I see your form wants `user`field to be filled. It means input from client, not from the code.

Comment: Since you get the user from request, why do you even need it as a field in the form? If you need to show the current user there, you can either a) show request.user in the html template or b) prepopulate the form with read only data about the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks PatNowak and Radek!

I did not know the form was waiting for user input instead of code input. I managed to fix it by adding exclude to the ModelForm.

```
class HulpOproepForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HulpOproep
        exclude = ['user', 'time']
```